# Cycles Render, Looks wrong in Render ViewPort, correct in Material ViewPort

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Using Cycles Render! Have tried things for hours on end and can't figure it out, please help!

I simply want to bake the texture from the Material Viewport, but it continues to bake the looks of the Render Viewport. Why is Render Viewport so extremely different looking?

[image: Bad Texture Colors]
[image: Correct Texture Colors, But Baked Diffuse Map uses incorrect/Render Version]

Comment: Material viewport is approximation, it can't be used as reference point for results of baking certain pass. Note also that network of nodes results only in Diffuse shader and ColorRamp node connected right into Mix shader node (which is incorrect since output of ColorRamp is color not shader). It's not clear which pass are you trying to bake though

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way to texture Bake the "active viewport" similarly to the openGL render active viewport option, but instead of a viewport unwrap it to the texture UVs to be saved as an image, such as in a texture Bake? Thanks!

Comment: No, generally there isn't. Instead I would advise to go with standard rendered shading. For speeding it up use Node Wrangler addon and Ctrl+Shift+left click on nodes to get their current preview on the model. It would be probably possible to go with your existing result if fixing the node setup as mentioned before (ColorRamp should not go to shader input) and baking resulting nodes into texture